# Java: I can't interact with my JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

I have a java application (1.4.2) that uses 2 JFrames.

The first is Modal=true and appears on top of the second JFrame.

The first JFrame allows the user to "open" a file.  Once the file is ready to be displayed, the JFrame is set to setModal=false, and this.dispose() 'd of.

This leaves only the second JFrame on the screen.  However, I can't interact with it.  The code does not throw any errors and appears to run perfectly fine.  BUT I can;t interact with the second JFrame.  The ONLY way to exit the JFrame is to hit the stop button on my development envirnment.  I literally cannot stop the JFrame by clicking the close button, because I can't even interact with that portion of the JFrame.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Some code would be nice to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also please accept some of your previous answers to questions, or people will not answer your questions.

Comment: Can you strip the code to bare minimum that causes the problem and post it ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know you could toggle modality.
Create a FileChooser in a modal dialog and simply dispose of the dialog when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem myself. It turned out that I had unintentionally set the enabled attribute of my JFrame to false. Make sure that your JFrame is enabled whenever you want the user to be able to interact with it:

```
jFrame.setEnabled(true);
```

The Javadoc for the setEnabled method says, "Disabling a heavyweight container prevents all components in this container from receiving any input events," which explains why Wooooo and I weren't able to interact with our JFrames at all.